# GMO payment gateway password validation conflicts with that of API

Tags: payment-gateway

I'm trying to integrate [GMO payment gateway](https://www.gmo-pg.com/en/) into my Ruby on Rails app, but I got stuck at this issue:

when I first login to shop management screen, GMO forces me to use a password that contains at least 1 symbol (!#% & + -. / :=? [] _) , but if I use this password to call an API, it keeps returning an error saying that my password is in valid because it contains a non-alphabet charactor (code E01020008). I would really appreciate if someone can give me any idea about this.

[password validation description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF7gp.png)

Comment: I figured it out, the shop password for api is different from the password used for logging in. To find the shop password for api: Shop management screen -> Shop management -> Basic information -> Shop-Password

Comment: well done, sounds worth an answer :-)